# SSRS 2008 - refresh report without requerying data?

Tags: ssrs-2008

I have four parameters on my report.  Three of them are required for the underlying stored procedure data source, but the fourth parameter is just used to show/hide items on the report.

If the user changes the value for that fourth parameter, is there a way to refresh the report using the existing data without running the stored procedure again? The result set won't change, only the rows that are to be displayed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reporting Services 2008 seems to treat each combination of report parameters as a unique set, even if some of them are internal to the report only, and not related to the stored procedure.  Therefore, aside from using report caching, there is no way to prevent report server from making a round trip to the database, even if only the internal parameter changes.  You basically have two options:

1. Turn on report caching in report server, and run all combinations of
   the four parameters,    so that the user will be accessing report
   server's cache when she runs any report.  This avoids making a round trip to the database, but only for the parameter values you've already tried.
2. write your underlying stored procedure with caching behavior so that it writes its results to a database table.  Whenever the stored procedure is run, have it first check the table to see if the results for the current set of parameter values is already stored in the cache table, and if so return those rows to report server.  This still requires a round trip, but it is faster than running the procedure again.